# Documents directory path of simulator in Xcode 6

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode6

Any idea why Apple changed the documents directory path in Xcode 6? I read [pinkstone's](http://pinkstone.co.uk/where-is-the-documents-directory-for-the-ios-8-simulator/) post but curious to know whether there is an explanation for the change.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator architecture was rewritten on top of a new framework called CoreSimulator.framework.  As part of that, you now have a library of devices that you can create or delete for your testing rather than just having one path of data that is used for all devices.